# UIAlertController only in specific time

Tags: ios, swift, alert

Is it possible to show alert `UIAlertController` only in specific time without click the `UIButton`? For example, when user run my game 3rd time. But if he click cancel then he'll never see it anymore.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let opensCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "open_count") + 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(opensCount, forKey: "open_count")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        return true
    }
```

and

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "open_count") == 3 {
            self.showAlert()
        }

...
    }
```

Comment: It is possible, of course. You can run code based on events other than user interaction (notifications, property observers, etc). By _"user run my game at the 3rd time"_ do you mean open the app or restart the game inside your app?

Comment: @DávidPásztor actually it's not so important. I just don't want show this alert too quickly for user. Want to let him play a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can add an integer to count the number of opens of the app and save it in the user defaults, then you check it, if it's equal to 3, you show the alert, and if it's canceled by the user you save a value also in the user defaults to prevent the alert from showing.

your code can be like that:

```
 \\this function to create the alert and present it 
 func showAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your Title", message: "Your Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
        /*do your action here on cancel*/
    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in
        /*do your action here on ok*/
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and in viewdidload call you can do like that:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "open_count") == 3 {
        self.showAlert()
    }
}
```

you can add this code in your app delegate, this method will be called every time the app finish launching :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //initial count + 1 the count of this current open
    let opensCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "open_count") + 1
    //set the new count value
    UserDefaults.standard.set(opensCount, forKey: "open_count")
    //dont forget to synchronize your user defaults
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    return true
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! But where should I set UserDefaults.standard in the code?

Comment: you're welcome, I edited the last part to show you where to set the user defaults.

Comment: Thank you! Strange but it doesn't work. `'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey' has been renamed to 'UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey'`. I changed and also added `return true` after `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` but anyway it doesn't work. Can you help me why?

Comment: Added above. Thank you very much!

Comment: are you accessing GameViewController in your app ?? , because i cant find any issue in your code

Comment: yes I have `var viewController : GameViewController!` :(